# Replace space character with + symbols in a link generator

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I created the following link generator for WhatsApp messages.

If someone writes a message with spaces, I would like them to be replaced with + in order for the link not to break if someone sends it as a plain message.

So for example, if the message is 'This is a test', the URL should be '...?text=this+is+a+test'

How can that be done with jQuery?

**HTML Code**

```html
<div class="bodyContainer" dir="rtl"><BR>
  <CENTER>
    <form id="linkgenform">
      <p class="labletext"><label for="phonenumber"> Phone number </label></p>
      <input type="number" id="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone number" />
      <P>
      <p class="labletext">
        <label for="message">
          Message
        </label>
      </p>
      <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Please let me know..." /><BR>
      <button dir="ltr" class="getlinkBtn"></i> Get link</button>
    </form>
    <BR>
    <div class="copylinkSection">
      <p class="labletext">
        <label for="finalLink">Your link:</label>
      </p>
      <input type="text" readonly id="finalLink" />

      <button dir="ltr" class="js-textareacopybtn2">copy</button>
    </div>
  </CENTER>
</div>
```

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#linkgenform");
const message = document.querySelector("#message");
const phonenumber = document.querySelector("#phonenumber");
const copylinkSection = document.querySelector(".copylinkSection");

/* add event listener to getbutton */
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (message.value != "" && phonenumber.value != "") {
    giveLink(Number(phonenumber.value), message.value);
  } else {
    alert("Please Fill the form");
  }
});

function giveLink(num, text) {
  copylinkSection.style.display = "flex";
  document.querySelector(
    "#finalLink"
  ).value = `https://wa.me/${num}?text=${text}`;
}

//copy the link function
const copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector(".js-textareacopybtn2");

copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  let copyTextarea = document.querySelector("#finalLink");
  copyTextarea.focus();
  copyTextarea.select();

  try {
    let successful = document.execCommand("copy");
    let msg = successful ? "successful" : "unsuccessful";
    alert("Text Copied " + msg + "!");
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Oops, unable to copy");
  }
});
```

Comment: Wondering why you've tagged jQuery and not used it the code you have shared!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```js
text = text.replaceAll(' ','+');
```

to replace all spaces with `+`. Full code:

```html
<div class="bodyContainer" dir="rtl"><br />
    <center>
        <form id="linkgenform">
            <p class="labletext"><label for="phonenumber">  Phone number </label></p>
            <input type="number" id="phonenumber" placeholder="Phone number" />
            <p class="labletext">
                <label for="message">Message</label>
            </p>
            <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Please let me know..." /><br />
            <button dir="ltr" class="getlinkBtn"> Get link</button>
        </form>
    </center>
    <br />
    <div class="copylinkSection">
        <p class="labletext">
            <label for="finalLink">Your link:</label>
        </p>
        <input type="text" readonly id="finalLink" />

        <button dir="ltr" class="js-textareacopybtn2">copy</button>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- script -->
<script>
    const form = document.querySelector("#linkgenform");
    const message = document.querySelector("#message");
    const phonenumber = document.querySelector("#phonenumber");
    const copylinkSection = document.querySelector(".copylinkSection");

    /* add event listener to getbutton */
    form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (message.value != "" && phonenumber.value != "") {
            giveLink(Number(phonenumber.value), message.value);
        } else {
            alert("Please Fill the form");
        }
    });

    function giveLink(num, text) {
        copylinkSection.style.display = "flex";
        text = text.replaceAll(' ','+');
        document.querySelector(
            "#finalLink"
        ).value = `https://wa.me/${num}?text=${text}`;
    }

    //copy the link function
    const copyTextareaBtn = document.querySelector(".js-textareacopybtn2");

    copyTextareaBtn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        let copyTextarea = document.querySelector("#finalLink");
        copyTextarea.focus();
        copyTextarea.select();

        try {
            let successful = document.execCommand("copy");
            let msg = successful ? "successful" : "unsuccessful";
            alert("Text Copied " + msg + "!");
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Oops, unable to copy");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the clearest answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `string.replace` function.

```js
 var text = 'This is test';
 text = text.replace(/ /g, '+');
 console.log(text);
```

```
function giveLink(num, text) {
  text = text.replace('/ /g,'+');
  copylinkSection.style.display = "flex";
  document.querySelector(
    "#finalLink"
  ).value = `https://wa.me/${num}?text=${text}`;
}
```

I think is enough if you replace with spaces in the function, it will return the link in the correct form

Read more on [w3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

Comment: Thanks but how can I ensure this is applied to all var text, regardless to the example I gave? 
This is a link generator so the message will change.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex replace.

```js
let str = "This is a  test";
console.log(str.replace(/\s+/g, "+"));
```

output

```
This+is+a+test
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I ensure this is applied to all var text, regardless to the example I gave? 
This is a link generator so the message will change.